# MDX - set member by another member values

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

I have this table generated with MDX.

    http://i62.tinypic.com/2m5xeg0.jpg

I need to create a calculated dimension (or a measure) called "this year" with 2 values:
  YES: if currentmember YEAR includes value 2015 and 
  NO: if member YEAR does not include 2015 for every CLIENT ID 
   http://i57.tinypic.com/2h508yx.jpg 
The MDX code is:

```
SELECT
    NON EMPTY {[Measures].[QUANTITY]} ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY CrossJoin({CLIENT ID].[CLIENT ID].Members, {[YEAR].[YEAR].Members}) ON ROWS
FROM
    [MyCube]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like the following:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[is2015] AS 
    IIF
    (
      Isnull(Instr(0,[YEAR].[YEAR].CurrentMember.Member_Caption,"2015"))  //<<unsure if the 2nd argumnet should read: [YEAR].CurrentMember.Member_Caption
     ,"YES"
     ,"NO"
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[QUANTITY]
     ,[Measures].[is2015]         
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [CLIENT ID].[CLIENT ID].MEMBERS
     ,{[YEAR].[YEAR].MEMBERS}
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube];
```

Here is the `MSDN` documentation for the `Instr` function used within `mdx`:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh758424.aspx

Referring to your screen-print please try this alternative:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[is2015] AS 
    IIF
    (
        NonEmpty
        (
          [CLIENT ID].[CLIENT ID].CurrentMember
         ,[YEAR].[YEAR].[2015]
        ).Count
      > 0
     ,"YES"
     ,"NO"
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[QUANTITY]
     ,[Measures].[is2015]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [CLIENT ID].[CLIENT ID].MEMBERS
     ,{[YEAR].[YEAR].MEMBERS}
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube];
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but is not quite the solution i need here. The [Measure].[is2015] should be for the whole "CLIENT ID" member, not for every single YEAR in row. If a certain client (40407 in this case) should have YES to all [YEAR] because it includes value "2015" (img. 2). I think a calculated dimension would be more appropriate, but I don't know how to set it. I forgot to mention I use MONDRIAN.

Comment: ok - this is still easy enough via the `NonEmpty` function. Do you have `NonEmpty` in Mondrian?

Comment: WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[is2015] AS 
    IIF
    (
      Isnull(Instr(0,[YEAR].[YEAR].CurrentMember.Properties("MEMBER_CAPTION"),"2015"))
     ,"YES"
     ,"NO"
    ) returns error: **MondrianException: Mondrian Error:No function matches signature 'Isnull(<Integer>)'** and the same error appears with the nonempty function. Mondrian has both function but it seems that something is wrong

Comment: **MondrianException: Mondrian Error:No function matches signature 'NonEmpty(<Integer>)'**

Comment: @ElizaM  as I noted in first script, you might need to try this `[YEAR].CurrentMember.Member_Caption` instead of this `[YEAR].[YEAR].CurrentMember.Member_Caption`. Similarly in the second you might like to try this `[CLIENT ID].CurrentMember` instead of this `[CLIENT ID].[CLIENT ID].CurrentMember`

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much! The alternative answer worked perfectly in Mondrian with very little changes:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[is2015] AS 
    IIF
    (
        (
          [CLIENT ID].CurrentMember
         ,[YEAR].[2015]
        )
      > 0
     ,"YES"
     ,"NO"
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {
      [Measures].[QUANTITY]
     ,[Measures].[is2015]
    } ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [CLIENT ID].[CLIENT ID].MEMBERS
     ,{[YEAR].[YEAR].MEMBERS}
    ) ON ROWS
FROM [MyCube];
```

Comment: If your cube is big then it would be good to replace `"NO"` with `null`. `IIF` measures run more efficiently if one of the branches resolves to null as the calculation will be sparse and therefore quicker.